# Magento Downloader hangs up while trying to install Mage_all_Latest

Tags: magento

i have installed a magento Version 1.9.1.0 since a few months, everything works fine.
Since a few weeks i'm trying to update Magento via the package Mage_All_Latest via the Magento Downloader, but nothing happens. I tried it in the last weeks with Version 1.9.1.1 - and since today with the brand new 1.9.2.0 - doesn't matter which - it doesn't work.
In the green status window it tells me "Checking dependencies of packages" - and that's it. No Error, no message - just nothing.
I tried this multiple times, nothing is going on - for hours!
The package is not in the /downloader/.cache-Directory.
When trying to upgrade single packages manually via downloader it always tells me things like

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.1.0" - but i cannot update this package...!
```

There is enough space available on the server.
The downloader itself has no problems - i tried to install all available packages in different relations and some worked:

```
Checking dependencies of packages
Starting to download Lib_Varien-1.9.2.0.tgz ...
...done: 157,974 bytes
Installing package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.0
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.0 installed successfully
```

I cannot access the server via SSH.
Is there any other option to upgrade this package? do i have to download the full new Magento installation package and override all files manually? or can i download this "Mage_all_latest"-Package on the magentocommerce-Website and replace all files manually? Is there any other option?
Does anybody have an idea what to do?
There is no error message :-(
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the server via FTP?
The magento downloader is garbage. You're better off downloading the extension from connect with this:
http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
and then uploading the files

Comment: Hi, i solved the problem with uploading a new version of magento and installing it on the old database. Before i copyied my template files etc. That worked. Next time i will watch your soultion, i think this would be much easier... Thank you!